# How to load all app resources so that you can interact with existing code?

Tags: scala, console, read-eval-print-loop

This was something that was extremely handy in Rails, for developers to jump in via `rails c`,
you can run querys with existing models like

> user_with_no_password = User.where(password: nil)

How to achieve this in Scala?

> user = UserDAO.all

```
  ^
       error: not found: type UserDAO
```

Comment: Is really not clear what you want to do and why.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez So I'm trying to run scala command to quickly poke at the application.

Comment: Scala has no such functionality and neither does any other language. You are somehow comparing `scala` to `RoR` which is a framework (and not a language) and ActiveRecord in RoR gives you all of this. You can write your proper DAO (using whatever framework, library you want) in Scala and use it.

Answer (score 2):

If you use sbt, you can use the `console` command in the sbt shell to launch a Scala REPL where all the code in your project can be used.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm doing actually, but I'm getting that not found issue, is there a particular format in which I need to be importing the packages?

Comment: No, you just use the normal import syntax.
Note that if you're using a multi-project build, you need to run the `console` command scoped to the right subproject, e. g. `myProject/console`

Comment: What import statement are you using? I'm failing with "com.eample.user._"